# How can I decide whether I can use a Raspberry Pi for my application?

Tags: microprocessor, raspberry-pi, imageprocessing

How do I calculate whether some specific hardware can run my code with a given speed?

It's an image recognition software, and a simplified version of the algorithm is:

1. Grab a frame (in RGB, 640x480).
2. Crop it to a given ROI (Region of interest). In my case this would be a 60x60 window, so all the following processing doesn't have to go through all of the pixels, just the ones inside the ROI.
3. Create a binary image (each pixel has either a '1' or a '0' value), by going through each pixel and applying a simple rule (involving only the intensities of the color of that specific pixel) to decide if that position will have a '1' or a '0' value. This is actually just a color threshold, here's an [example](http://s9.postimg.org/b6poxcf6n/threshold_pingpongball.jpg) of the input and output of this step. In the example the rule is "does the color of the pixel is orange?".
4. Calculate the geometric center of the binary image created in the last step. This is done simply:

   ```
   scan the image for valued-1 pixels;
   save the coordinates of those pixels in two vectors, one named 'ind_x' and another 'ind_y';
   GCx = mean(indices_x);
   Gcy = mean(indices_y);
   ```
5. Output the `Gcx` and `Gcy` through serial communication.

I'm trying to figure out wheter a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) could process this code 120-times a second (or more specifically, at what rate this could be done in it).

I believe the answer to this question could benefit electronics.stackexchange as well, since it could be abstracted to answer the more general question: given a rough description of an algorithm (clear enough so that one could estimate the complexity of the code) how can I predict whether some specified hardware can process it with a given time constraint?

If more details are needed please say so in the comments.

Comment: This is an issue of algorithmic analysis, and not specifically related to EE: you specify your algorithm to the necessary degree of precision (high-level: rough operations, low-level: write it in assembly) and then check the execution speed on your particular platform.

Comment: Check it on the actual hardware?

Comment: Obviously, steps 2-4 are no problem for a CPU of the type the RPi contains, and step 5 shouldn't be a bottleneck either. The real question in my mind would be step 1: Is there a combination of hardware and driver that can actually get 120 fps of raw video *into* the RPi?

Comment: There's a big difference between the throughput of video processing performed by the pi's ARM cpu core, vs that which might theoretically be achieved using its GPU, if implemented by someone with access to the proprietary Broadcomm programming information.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is more of an opinion than a typical definitive stackoverflow type answer, but here it goes.

I tried using a Raspberry Pi for image processing for my capstone project. Perhaps it was just the libraries, or having a bunch of stuff on USB, but I was extremely unsatisfied with its performance. It had a hard time streaming VGA images at any appreciable framerate, let alone doing any sort of image processing with them and then streaming it over.

I mean, there's a lot of variables (especially wrt code optimization and implementation), and I can't speak objectively and quantitatively, but you get the performance you would expect out of a computer you would only paid $30 for. I would suggest taking a look at Odroid X2 which has far more hardware kick, although I haven't used one myself.

You could buy one and try it and see if it meets your demands; you'd be out only $30 if it didn't. But based on my own personal experience with this thing I really doubt this thing can do what you want at 120x a second.

Comment: I'd say the majority of the issue is a lack of optimised software - fundamentally the Pi is capable of HD video capture & playback so capturing low-res images and doing some basic maths should be more than doable. Whether you can be bothered to do the optimisation Vs throwing more CPU cycles at it with "better" hardware is down to you.

Comment: @JohnU - not really.  The real video potential of the pi comes from the GPU of its SOC, but the programming information for that has not been released to the public.  As a result, most users can only realize its true potential when doing a task for which GPU code has already been written by the pi foundation or someone else with access to the tightly held Broadcomm docs.  Video tasks running on the ARM core such as typical users have the necessary information to write are going to tend to be much slower - and that's not the fault of the users, but of the refusal to release full docs.